# Angular - Trigger file writing on node server

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am new to both Angular and Node. Might be a stupid question, but how do I setup Angular and Node to trigger writing into a file on the Node server? 
Or, to put question the other way around: How do I access node modules from my Angular frontend implementation and get the results back via callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$http` service of AngularJS. For more info have a look [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)